# $_GET index isset

Tags: php, get, isset

This is my URL :

```
http://localhost/messources/actes/palactes.php?mode=MODE_NEW
```

In php I have this :

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
            }else{
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
            }
```

since id is not in the URL, I would expect this entire block not to be executed.  $_GET['id'] doesn't exist, so the value should be NULL therefore isset() testing that.

However, I get a php notice  :

```
Undefined index: id in ....
```

What should I do to get rid of that notice (I don't want to add  &id=  to the url)

Comment: Did you started your session? I probably guess the error is on this line: `$_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];`

Comment: `$_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];` - this is definitely meaningless

Comment: I started my session with session_start() and $_SESSION['id'] may still be NULL since no $_GET['id'] was set.

Comment: Show the form or wherever you GET the id

Comment: you just need to get rid of your else branch. it's doing nothing more than without it and it throws notice because  $_SESSION['id'] is not set yet

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 session_start();// Only if you havent started.

if (isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
            }else{
                $_SESSION['id'] = 0;
            }
```

And you can check if its 0 or not . If 0 then, NOt logged in else logged in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of - `$_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];`.

Do this -

```
        if (isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_GET['id'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = NULL;
}

if(! isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
}
```

This doesn't run when $_SESSION['id'] is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your reading from id in the session is undefined

```
   $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question,

> What should I do to get rid of that notice (I don't want to add &id=
>   to the url)

And your URL is

```
http://localhost/messources/actes/palactes.php?mode=MODE_NEW
```

Your PHP code has

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
            }else{
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
            }
```

1) How do you assign a value to your `$_GET['id']` because with what you have on your `URL` `$_GET['id']` will always return `NULL` since it has no values from anywhere. You can test by doing `var_dump($_GET);` and your `$_SESSION['id']` will also return `NULL`. Test again using `var_dump($_SESSION);`. You must give it a value before you can get anything assigned to `$_GET['id']`. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) , that checks if it exists and is not one of the following values:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So as I would rewrite your code is

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
}
```